# No longer able to move messages in Thunderbird using HUD in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: unity, 14.04, thunderbird, hud

I used to use the HUD in Thunderbird to move email messages to different folders.  I found this a useful feature in Ubuntu 12.04 as I have a lot of email folders and it is quicker to use the HUD than using the right click menu to navigate through all of my folders.  I simply needed to press 'Alt' to bring up the HUD and then type "move to " (actually you could shorten this further to "mo ").

I've recently upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04 and this no longer seems to work.  I can still access the HUD and complete actions such as "New message" but I can't move messages to other folders.

Does anyone know why this is and if it is possible to get this functionality back?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if any of your background aplication intercept alt as a hotkey. It can also be system key, I'm not familiar with Ubuntu keyboard shortcuts since I'm using Xubuntu and this thing differs. Alt can probably affect your windows movement.

Comment: I'm able to bring up the HUD using the alt key.  That's not the problem.  The issue is that I can no longer use it to move messages.